# Kubuntu upgrade broke KDE programs

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, 15.10, fedora

I upgraded to Kubuntu 15.10 from 15.04 on Friday. I use Awesome WM with the KDE programs. After the upgrade they seemed rather broken.

A fresh user account with KDE has the problem that KDE starts very slowly (on an i5 with SSD). The panel at the bottom takes a couple minutes to place the elements properly.

Is there something I can do except wait or change the Linux distribution?

---

In the meantime I have installed Fedora 22 on my laptop. It worked just fine there. Now I did the upgrade to Fedora 23 yesterday. Today I started Dolphin and saw the dreaded error again.

This tells me that this problem is not Ubuntu specific but rather has something to do with KDE and/or my configuration. My configuration did not change and worked when I went to an older KDE version by switching to Fedora. Now this got back to me and I would like to solve this.

Comment: Did you try doing a fresh install? As things can break during a standard upgrade.

Comment: No I have not tried that yet. I am on the go and as I have full disk encryption I also have to restore my data from a backup. That would be an option, of course, but I'd rather not reinstall the thing every six months.

Comment: I have the same problem, using kde display manager. After the upgrade to Kubuntu 15.10, many applictions have their UI complety broken. What's really strange is that applications that exibits this problem are all kde / qt applications. Gtk applications run and display juste fine.

Comment: I just installed Fedora 22 on said machine. There it all works even with my `/home` directory in place

Comment: I think this is a ubuntu bug. I have created a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1510899

Comment: @Zoltan Actually, it is not an Ubuntu bug :-). It comes from Qt 5 and the transition to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across an [Arch Linux BBS post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201931) where the same issue is described. Once I thought that this was an issue with multiple distributions and just Ubuntu I was looking at more stuff. There is a [helpful url](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE#KF5.2FQt5_applications_don.27t_display_icons_in_i3.2Ffvwm.2Fawesome) which directs to the [configuration of Qt 5 using no desktop environment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Qt#Configuration_of_Qt_apps_under_environments_other_than_KDE) which is exactly the case that I have here with Awesome WM.

Since there is no `qt5cf` package in Fedora 23, I just faked the environment variable `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE` and got the icons back.

The strange error with the home directory is easily cured by manually setting the standard directory to `/home/USER`.

Dolphin now works for me again I think. The problem was the transition to Qt 5 and had nothing to do with Ubuntu in particular.